# Remove Row on GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

A gridtable has 5 rows which was filled by database.
If we want to remove somerow on it.

### Solution:

Create a datatableTemp, After remove on gridView, It will remove a table Temp too.
After that,It will be fill GridView by tableTemp.

```
//========Get datatable from database.
dtTempGrdBlockForDeviceByRole = Cls_BLOCKS.getDataTable_WriteField();
grdBlockForDeviceByRole = Cls_BLOCKS.getDataTable_WriteField();            
for (int x = 0; x < grdBlockForDeviceByRole.Rows.Count; x++)
{
    CheckBox chk = grdBlockForDeviceByRole.Rows[x].FindControl("ckDelete") as CheckBox;
    string txtD = grdBlockForDeviceByRole.Rows[x].Cells[0].Text;                
    if (chk.Checked)
    {
        //If choice   
        //What should we do in here?         
    }                
}
grdBlockForDeviceByRole.DataSource = dtTempGrdBlockForDeviceByRole;
grdBlockForDeviceByRole.DataBind();
```

May you help me?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I edit "What should we do?"

Answer (score 1):

you can use the code as follows.

```
dtTempGrdBlockForDeviceByRole = Cls_BLOCKS.getDataTable_WriteField();
grdBlockForDeviceByRole = Cls_BLOCKS.getDataTable_WriteField();            
for (int x = 0; x < grdBlockForDeviceByRole.Rows.Count; x++)
{
    CheckBox chk = grdBlockForDeviceByRole.Rows[x].FindControl("ckDelete") as CheckBox;
    string txtD = grdBlockForDeviceByRole.Rows[x].Cells[0].Text;                
    if (chk.Checked)
    {
        dtTempGrdBlockForDeviceByRole.Rows.RemoveAt(x);  
    }                
}
grdBlockForDeviceByRole.DataSource = dtTempGrdBlockForDeviceByRole;
grdBlockForDeviceByRole.DataBind();
```

Thanks

Comment: It show "There is no row at position 3." error message when I debug delete row 1,2,3,4.When it delete row index 4,It will show that error message.I think that  "dtTempGrdBlockForDeviceByRole.Rows.RemoveAt(x);" not work fine.

Comment: please check   grdBlockForDeviceByRole.Rows.Count(); and  dtTempGrdBlockForDeviceByRole.Rows.count();

Comment: I which event you are using the code?

Comment: I have solution for it.if (chk.Checked)
                        //If choice            
                        for (int y = 0; y < dtTempGrdBlockForDeviceByRole.Rows.Count; y++)
                        {
                            string txtY = dtTempGrdBlockForDeviceByRole.Rows[y][0].ToString();
                            if (txtD.Contains(txtY))
                                dtTempGrdBlockForDeviceByRole.Rows.RemoveAt(y);
                        }.Thanks